# Google TimeZone API in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-api-client

I am using the Google Places API in Android: retrieving the place details via the `PlaceAutoCompleteFragment`. However, the results (in the form of the `IPlace` interface, do not include TimeZone information, and I can't find an Android-specific implementation of the Google TimeZone API.

I could use `ModernHttpClient` to do a web-based call to the API, but for that I would need to add an API key with no restrictions, and I'm loath to do that. Is there in fact an Android-specific implementation of the Google TimeZone API that I might have missed?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the timezone of each place, or just the timezone that the device/user is in?

Comment: The latter. The idea is that an admin user can set up venues for events, and those venues may be in other timezones.

Comment: So we need to know the timezone of each individual venue.

Comment: Google TimeZone API is great, the downside is that it is a server-based API key license, plus side is it is really cheap and easy to use..., but there are a number of free/freemium/premium timezone db/csv (and online API) available in the wild to do this offline if needed. I downloaded a set of csv-based timezone files and loaded them into a Ream database, a few Linq queries later....

Comment: Nice. I think I'll go with the GeoTimeZone NuGet package for MVP.